# Simple rewrite rule is not working on Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When trying to create URL rewrite rules on my server, I ran into some problems so wanted to test if it was working at all with a more simple case: The URL `example.com/test` should be rewritten as `example.com/index.php`, a real page that exists on my site.

Here is the full content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off

SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   test.php   index.php
```

And the result when I enter the URL `example.com/test.php`:

> 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on this server.

I made the `.htaccess` document slightly more simple for this test than it usually is. Usually, I also have the following rules in the document:

```
# Redirect from non-www to www

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

These rules have always worked as they should. Is there something wrong with my test rewrite rule, and if not, why are the rewrite rules working for www and HTTPS redirection?

This is the structure of the files on my server:

```
| .htaccess
| www
| -- index.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Place your https and www implementing rules at top of your file.

Make sure your htaccess and index.php files are in root directory.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^test/?$   index.php [NC,L]
```

Change the structure of htaccess as follows with your shown samples apart from few minor other changes in htaccess(like fixed regex for redirection, used `NE` flag in redirection, combined Rules for https and www redirects etc; to improve your rules file)

```
| .htaccess
| www
| -- index.php
| -- .htaccess (new)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! The problem appears to have been that `index.php` was inside the `www` directory, while `.htaccess` was in the same directory as the `www` folder. If I create a new file within `www` and add your code, it works perfectly. Although I'm still not sure I understand why the same code does not work when it is in the root directory containing `www`?

Comment: @Run_Script, since we are not giving any part in rewrite rule that's why it needs to be on same location where htacess resides at, so your system could find it. I am happy my code is working for you. Cheers and happy learning 

Comment: @Run_Script, With all respect, I would like to edit your question and would add your fixed path in my answer as questions are meant to keep only query part, I hope you wouldn't mind, let me edit it now.

Comment: Yes that's great, thanks! If I could ask one follow-up question: is there any way of changing the rewrite rule so that the two files *don't* both have to be in the root directory?

Comment: @Run_Script, yes you could create one more htaccess(1 keep it inside `www` AND one to keep besides with it) but then it will complicate the things(you may need to use inherit option to inherit rules from 1st htaccess(sitting besides www) to inner one but IMHO better to have it in this way. Cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks. You saved me. Rule order was my issue